# can't retrieve data from database phpMyAdmin

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

I'm a beginner in learning how to set up database & PHP script and follow example 
to do that, then when I run login.php script I can't retrieve data from the database ,
I really feel that is a very simple question for others but I tried to solve it But didn't succeed, so can someone take look on my code then Corrects it?

here is my php script :

init.php :

```
<?php
    $db_name = "webapp";
    $mysql_username = "root";
    $mysql_password = "";
    $server_name = "localhost";
    $con=mysqli_connect($server_name, $mysql_username, $mysql_password, $db_name);

    if (!$con)  {
        echo "Connection Error ......." . mysqli_connect_error();
    } else {
        echo "<h3>Database connection Success .....</h3>";
    }
?>
```

login.php :

```
<?php
    require "init.php";
    $user_name = "YASER";
    $user_phone = "123456";

    $sql_query = "select name from user_info where user_name like'$user_name'and
        user_phone like'$user_phone';";

    $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql_query);
    if (mysqli_num_rows($result)>0)
    {
        $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
        $name = $row["name"];
        echo "<h3> Hello And Wellcome" . $name . "</h3>";
    }  else  {
        echo " No Info Is Available .......";
    }
?>
```

[image: this is the result]

Comment: Your code is pretty messy - try removing the semicolon from sql statement, add some spaces between words, try again ad come back with the progress

Comment: You should use `=` instead of `like`

Comment: *1st:*  First check that query is executing or failing `if(!$result){ echo mysqli_error($con); }`   *2nd :* use `=` instead of `like`

Comment: `var_dump` your $result and $con, then post it here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1st :** First check that query is `executing` or `failing`

```
if(!$result){ echo mysqli_error($con); }
```

**2nd :** use `=` instead of `like`

```
$sql_query = "select name from user_info 
              where user_name='$user_name' and
              user_phone='$user_phone'";
```

**3rd :** You need to give **proper spacing** In query

```
like'$user_name'and
   ^^^        ^^^
```

To

```
like '$user_name' and
```

Answer (score 0):

You have error in your query.

try this to find error

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql_query) or die(mysqli_error($con));
```

Your query should be like as follow...

```
'SELECT name FROM user_info WHERE user_name LIKE "'.$user_name.'" AND user_phone LIKE "'.$user_phone.'"';
```